# Get AlertDialog input

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I've got two customs `AlertDialog`. *All work since I can't get the input of the user, I've created a class called `MyDialog` and put the constructor.* Furthermore, I thought to put a getter with the `EditText`; nevertheless, I can't find the way to get the input.

Here is `MyDialog` class:

```
public class MyDialog {
    public static AlertDialog.Builder create(final Context context, final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final String title, final String content) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.userdialog, null);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitleDialog)).setText(title);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewContentDialog)).setText(content);
        ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etEmailNuevo)).getText();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(view);
    }

    public String getEmailNuevo(String NewEmail) {
        return NewEmail;
    }
}
```

I've created inside the `EditText` and instead of `setText()`, I put `getText()`; however, I'm using this class on my `Fragment` at the time. *I don't know how to call it. I tried with `getText().toString();` inside a `Toast`; nevertheless, it didn't show up.* What I've done wrong?

Here is where I've used this class:

```
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = MyDialog.create(context, getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState), "Cambio de email", "Introduce nuevo email");
myDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.canviaruserdialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    }
})
.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelaruserdialog, null)
.show();
```

### EDIT 1

I've changed my code to:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = MyDialog.create(context, getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState), "Cambio de email", "Introduce nuevo email");
final String pew = MyDialog.getEntry();
myDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.canviaruserdialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), pew, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelaruserdialog, null)
.show();
```

And my class looks like:

```
private static EditText mEditText;
public static AlertDialog.Builder create(final Context context, final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final String title, final String content) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.userdialog, null);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitleDialog)).setText(title);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewContentDialog)).setText(content);
    ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etEmailNuevo)).getText();
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(view);
}

public static String getEntry() {
    return mEditText.getText().toString();
}
```

And this is the ***Logcat error***:

```
2927-2927/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 2927
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MyDialog.getEntry(MyDialog.java:26)
    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.ConfiguracionFragment.onClick(ConfiguracionFragment.java:45)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

### Edit 2

I've changed the logic and now, I'm trying to do this way:

I've created an `EditText` and a `String` as follows:

```
EditText mEt;
private String m_Text = "";
```

Here is where I initiate this `EditText`:

```
mEt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etEmailNuevo);
```

Then, I do the `AlertDialog` as follows:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userdialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

final EditText input = mEt; //null<--------

input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);

builder.setPositiveButton("Cambiar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        m_Text = input.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), m_Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

builder.show();
```

However, *it is still giving me this `EditText` is null. **I don't know how to link this `EditText` with `R.id.etEmailNuevo` from `userdialog`.***

Comment: @Blackbelt Can't find the way to show in a Toast(for example) the text imput by theuser

Comment: @jlindenbaum I said I tried `getText().toString();` like in your url and didn't work to me, I can't get the text.

Comment: You really need to read up on [how to debug your app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @codeMagic I did, but I think my problem is because I'm trying to call a method that is not on my class, because I create a `AlertDialog.Builder` from my `MyDialog`, that's why I don't know how to call that method...

Comment: probably because `mEditText` is `null`

Comment: @codeMagic I tried to do `mEditText.findViewById(R.id.etEmailNuevo);` .... but nothing happens

Comment: `mEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.etEmailNuevo);`

Comment: @codeMagic Do you mean this inside of create method?

Comment: wherever you need to use it

Comment: I need it inside my get method, so if I put it inside I can't put the "view" since view is nothing, so I have to put the findViewById...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `getText()` correctly.

If you want to get the content of an EditText in your dialog, you should do the following:

1) In the MyDialog class, create a member variable for your EditText

```
private EditText mEditText;
```

Set the findViewById(R.id.etEmailNuevo) line to equal that.

2) Create a method which gets the current content of the EditText

```
public String getEntry() {
     return mEditText.getText().toString();
}
```

3) Then when you create your dialog, in onClick call this method and you're all set.

Comment: or he could use the `DialogInterface dialog` argument to look for the `EditText`

Comment: I tried to call MyDialog.getEntry() and say cannot resolve this method